# Creating a logger that wraps around winston and express-winston

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, typescript

I am trying to create a logger wrapper around winston and express-winston (enables middleware error log) that is configurable . How could i improve this code?

//logger.ts

```
import * as winston from "winston";
import * as FileSystem from "fs";

import AppConfig from "../config/app/appConfig";
import CoreUtils from "../../common/utils/core";

// Express winston does not yet have declaration support.
const expressWinston = require("express-winston");

export default class Logger {

    public static loggerInstance: Logger;
    private static readonly CONFIG_KEY: string = "log";
    private static readonly CONFIG_KEY_LEVEL: string = "level";
    private static readonly CONFIG_KEY_TRANSPORT: string = "transports";
    private static readonly CONFIG_KEY_ENABLE_MIDDLEWARE: string = "enableMiddleware";
    private static readonly TRANSPORT_KEY_CONSOLE: string = "console";
    private static readonly TRANSPORT_KEY_FILE: string = "file";
    private static readonly LOG_DIR: string = "log";

    /**
     * Ensures a single logger object is maintained throught application/
     */
    public static getInstance(): Logger {
        let loggerInstance: Logger = Logger.loggerInstance;
        if (CoreUtils.isNull(loggerInstance)) {
            Logger.loggerInstance = loggerInstance = new Logger();
        }
        return loggerInstance;
    }

    public isMiddlewareEnabled: boolean = false;
    private logger: winston.LoggerInstance;
    private transports: winston.TransportInstance[] = [];

    constructor() {
        this.initialize();
    }

    public info(msg: string, logObject?: any): void {
        this.logger.info(msg, logObject);
    }

    public error(msg: string, logObject?: any): void {
        this.logger.error(msg, logObject);
    }

    public warn(msg: string, logObject?: any): void {
        this.logger.warn(msg, logObject);
    }

    public debug(msg: string, logObject?: any): void {
        this.logger.debug(msg, logObject);
    }

    public trace(msg: string, logObject?: any): void {
        this.logger.verbose(msg, logObject);
    }

    /**
     * Get express winston middleware configuraion
     */
    public getMiddlewareLogger(): any {
        const options: any = {
            transports: this.transports
        };

        return expressWinston.logger(options);
    }

    private initialize() {
        const logConfig = AppConfig.getObject(Logger.CONFIG_KEY);
        const logLevel: string = logConfig[Logger.CONFIG_KEY_LEVEL];
        const logTransport: Object = logConfig[Logger.CONFIG_KEY_TRANSPORT];
        this.isMiddlewareEnabled = <boolean> logConfig[Logger.CONFIG_KEY_ENABLE_MIDDLEWARE];

        for (let key in logTransport) {
            if (logTransport.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (key === Logger.TRANSPORT_KEY_CONSOLE) {
                    this.configureConsoleTransport(logTransport[key], logLevel);
                } else if (key === Logger.TRANSPORT_KEY_FILE) {
                    this.configureFileTransport(logTransport[key]);
                }
            }
        }
        this.logger = new (winston.Logger)({
            transports: this.transports
        });
    }

    /**
     * Configuring console transport
     */
    private configureConsoleTransport(transport: Object, logLevel: string): void {
        const options: Object = Object.assign({
            "level": logLevel
        }, transport);
        this.transports.push(new (winston.transports.Console)(options));
    }

    /**
     * Configuring file transport
     */
    private configureFileTransport(transport: Object): void {
        const targetFileList: Object = AppConfig.getObject(Logger.CONFIG_KEY)["target"];

        // Creating log directory if it does not exist
        if (!FileSystem.existsSync(Logger.LOG_DIR)) {
            FileSystem.mkdirSync(Logger.LOG_DIR);
        }

        for (let key in targetFileList) {
            const options: Object = Object.assign({
                "name": key,
                "level": key,
                "filename": `${Logger.LOG_DIR}/${targetFileList[key]}`
            }, transport);
            this.transports.push(new (winston.transports.File)(options));
        }
    }
}
```

//config.json

```
"log": {
        "level": "info",
        "enableMiddleware": true,
        "transports": {
            "console": {
                "colorize": true,
                "timestamp": true,
                "json": false,
                "showLevel": true
            },
            "file": {                
                "json": true,
                "maxsize": "10485760",
                "maxfile": "5"
            } 
        },
        "target": {
            "trace": "trace.log",
            "debug": "debug.log",
            "error": "error.log",
            "warn": "info.log",
            "info": "info.log"
        }
    }
```

//usage in main.ts

```
import Logger from "../core/common/logging/logger";
...

if (Logger.getInstance().isMiddlewareEnabled) {
            this.app.use(Logger.getInstance().getMiddlewareLogger());
}
```

What could be done better?